# Making Git use PuTTY as SSH client on Windows 7

Tags: git, ssh, putty

I have generated the pair of keys using PuTTY, put the public one on the github.
Then I run authentication agent from Git Extensions, add key, click "Close" button, try to connect to GitHub, but got the message that access denied:
[image]

[image]

```
WL_Temp@proj ~/Projects/Squeaky (feature/STRINGERV2-182)
$ ssh -T git@github.com
Permission denied (publickey).

WL_Temp@proj ~/Projects/Squeaky (feature/STRINGERV2-182)
$ ssh -aT git@github.com
Permission denied (publickey).

WL_Temp@proj ~/Projects/Squeaky (feature/STRINGERV2-182)
$ ssh -vT git@github.com
OpenSSH_6.6.1, OpenSSL 1.0.1i 6 Aug 2014
debug1: Connecting to github.com [192.30.252.130] port 22.
debug1: Connection established.
debug1: identity file /c/Users/WL_Temp/.ssh/id_rsa type -1
debug1: identity file /c/Users/WL_Temp/.ssh/id_rsa-cert type -1
debug1: identity file /c/Users/WL_Temp/.ssh/id_dsa type -1
debug1: identity file /c/Users/WL_Temp/.ssh/id_dsa-cert type -1
debug1: identity file /c/Users/WL_Temp/.ssh/id_ecdsa type -1
debug1: identity file /c/Users/WL_Temp/.ssh/id_ecdsa-cert type -1
debug1: identity file /c/Users/WL_Temp/.ssh/id_ed25519 type -1
debug1: identity file /c/Users/WL_Temp/.ssh/id_ed25519-cert type -1
debug1: Enabling compatibility mode for protocol 2.0
debug1: Local version string SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_6.6.1
debug1: Remote protocol version 2.0, remote software version libssh-0.7.0
debug1: no match: libssh-0.7.0
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT sent
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT received
debug1: kex: server->client aes128-ctr hmac-sha1 none
debug1: kex: client->server aes128-ctr hmac-sha1 none
debug1: sending SSH2_MSG_KEX_ECDH_INIT
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_KEX_ECDH_REPLY
debug1: Server host key: RSA 16:27:ac:a5:76:28:2d:36:63:1b:56:4d:eb:df:a6:48
debug1: Host 'github.com' is known and matches the RSA host key.
debug1: Found key in /c/Users/WL_Temp/.ssh/known_hosts:1
debug1: ssh_rsa_verify: signature correct
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS sent
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS received
debug1: Roaming not allowed by server
debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_REQUEST sent
debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_ACCEPT received
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey
debug1: Next authentication method: publickey
debug1: Trying private key: /c/Users/WL_Temp/.ssh/id_rsa
debug1: Trying private key: /c/Users/WL_Temp/.ssh/id_dsa
debug1: Trying private key: /c/Users/WL_Temp/.ssh/id_ecdsa
debug1: Trying private key: /c/Users/WL_Temp/.ssh/id_ed25519
debug1: No more authentication methods to try.
Permission denied (publickey).
```

After that, it seems I tried everything that would help but failed. 
Is it solvable?

Answer (score 0):

`ssh-add -l` to verify that the `ssh` has access to your agent (it does not have since you don't see such a key being offered).

Also openssh does not work with PuTTY keys and agent. You would need to convert the keys from PuTTY format to openssh format to use them in them from terminal `ssh`.

Answer (score 0):

Git for Windows ships with a Windows build of the OpenSSH client, which is used by default.

It *is* able to work with PuTTY though—this is done through properly setting the `GIT_SSH` environment variable (and a little dance aronund PuTTY to make it trust the servers you connect to).

These matters are very well explained in [this guide](http://nathanj.github.io/gitguide/index.html).